# HTTP-Client: 'Auth cache not set in the context '- what is it?

Tags: httpclient

'Auth cache not set in the context' disappears if I set 'org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicAuthCache'.

However, for the life of me -- I can't fathom what 'org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicAuthCache' actual does - i.e. how long does it cache the credential for (if that is what it does)?